Can I use javascript to remove an image that doesn't contain an ID?
I' having a little trouble figuring this out. Is there a way to remove an image from a site page using Javascript if the image does not have an ID? Here's the on the site page with the link URL:
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/icons/markup.png" alt="Mark Up Icon" width="40" height="40" data-decorative="true">

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:
$("img[src='https://storage.googleapis.com/icons/markup.png']").remove();


by id you mean the id attribute on the img tag? You want to remove all the images in an document which do not have an id attribute on them right?

Hi, not all images - I'd like to just remove this specific image with this specific URL. Not sure if that's possible.

Is there any error in console?

Your code has no errors,  have you checked the google devtools and saw  some errors.

Yea, I dont see any errors, here is an codepen for the same https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/gOJbYaB?editors=1010

Also give document.querySelector(img[src="https://storage.googleapis.com/icons/markup.png"]).remove(); a shot, just incase you have made some mistake while importing jquery.

Code works fine as provided.  Did you check that selector?  console.log($("img[src='https://storage.googleapis.com/icons/markup.png']").length); before / after (https://jsfiddle.net/sh4en3qy/)?   If it's 0 before, it's the selector.   Are you running your code in the <head>?  In which case wrap it in doc.ready $(() => { ... });.  Are there any errors in the console or network tab, eg a 403 on jquery.js?  What is the url attribute?  console.log($("img").map((_, e) => e.src).get())  does it match what you are testing for?  Same case?

Thank you all! I ended up using Javascript and adding a 0.15 second time delay. It looks like the javascript was executing before the html was loaded. Not the most ideal solution, but it ended up working.

Your attribute selector has a problem. Try with double quotes instead of single quotes:
$('img[src="https://storage.googleapis.com/icons/markup.png"]').remove();


Does it?  No.   Swapping " and ' has no impact.

Thank you! I ended up using Javascript and adding a 0.15 second time delay. It looks like the javascript was executing before the html was loaded. Not the most ideal solution, but it ended up working.

Well, seems like your jquery was being loaded in the head or above body content with script tag and due to that reason it wasn't able to find any elements. A better approach than adding a timeout would be putting your <script src="..."></script> tag right above the </body> (closing body) tag and wrapping your jQuery/JS code inside a document ready listener: $(document).ready(function () { ... }); or $(function() { ... });. This way your code will execute when the document is loaded and ready, making sure jQuery/JS query selectors find the existing elements.

Please refer: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Thanks so much!! Let me see if I can get your approach to work on my end. The time delay definitely isn't ideal.

Thank you all! After a lot of testing, I ended up using Javascript and adding a 0.15 second time delay. It looks like the javascript was executing before the html was loaded. Not the most ideal solution, but it ended up working.
// Delay in milliseconds before executing the removeImages function
var delay = 150; // 0.15 seconds

// Set a timeout to delay the execution
setTimeout(removeImages, delay); 

});

